# hide and show of tabs in action bar

Tags: android, tabs, hide, show, android-actionbar

I am building an android app, for 3.0 with a compatibility package. I have an action bar, that contains 3 tabs. Also in the action bar I have the search, add and the icon for the overflow items. The problem is when I am in portrait mode and I click on the search icon (it expends itself for text input), so it is over the tabs. I saw in the YouTube app for tablets, that when such thing happens the tabs are somehow hidden, and when you click on the "x" to close the search view they are shown again. Does someone knows how this hiding and showing of the tabs in the action bar is done? I can't find anything about it.. 
I am testing on an actual device, motorola xoom. [image: search_closed][image: search_opened]

Answer (score 2):

I imagine they are using this method to show/hide the tabs:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Comment: I think that is to display the tabs. That's what I use in my activity class, when I set up the actionbar. But for hiding the tabs, I don't know. I tried using actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD); but then I have nothing on the screen. All of my fragments that are in the tabs are gone.

Comment: That's a shame. The next thing I'd do is use Hierarchy Viewer to look at the Views, and look to get access to the container View, so its Visibility status can be changed.

Comment: I didn't try the hierarchy viewer, it seemed a little complicated :S:) I found an alternative solution for my problem. Instead of hiding the tabs, I am hiding the other buttons that I have in the action bar (other than search, i have add, edit etc.), when search icon is selected. That way I get the space in the action bar that I need, and my tabs don't get overlapped. But thanx for your reply anyway!